# CUDA : 2D grid launch error

Tags: cuda

I am trying to launch a 2D grid with dimensions (65535x1000) but `cudaDeviceSynchronize` returns code error 6 . My device should support up to 65535 block in y dimension so I don't understand what is happening.Here is my code

```
#include "cuda_runtime.h"
#include "device_launch_parameters.h"
#include <stdio.h>

cudaError_t addWithCuda();

__global__ void kernel()
{
    int i = blockIdx.x*blockIdx.y;
}

int main()

{

cudaError_t cudaStatus;

// Choose which GPU to run on, change this on a multi-GPU system.
cudaStatus = cudaSetDevice(0);
if (cudaStatus != cudaSuccess) {
    fprintf(stderr, "cudaSetDevice failed!  Do you have a CUDA-capable GPU installed?");
}


// Launch a kernel on the GPU 
dim3 grid(65535,1000) ;
kernel<<<grid, 1024>>>();

// Check for any errors launching the kernel
cudaStatus = cudaGetLastError();
if (cudaStatus != cudaSuccess) {
    fprintf(stderr, "addKernel launch failed: %s\n", cudaGetErrorString(cudaStatus));
}

// cudaDeviceSynchronize waits for the kernel to finish, and returns
// any errors encountered during the launch.
cudaStatus = cudaDeviceSynchronize();

if (cudaStatus != cudaSuccess) {
    fprintf(stderr, "cudaDeviceSynchronize returned error code %d after launching Kernel!\n", cudaStatus);
}

// cudaDeviceReset must be called before exiting in order for profiling and
// tracing tools such as Nsight and Visual Profiler to show complete traces.
cudaStatus = cudaDeviceReset();
if (cudaStatus != cudaSuccess) {
    fprintf(stderr, "cudaDeviceReset failed!");
    return 1;
}
system("pause");
return 0;
```

}

Comment: What is your device? Which CUDA version? What is the actual error output string? What happens if you run the CUDA deviceQuery sample on your system? Are you running on windows?

Comment: ... and have you already tried small numbers instead of 65535x1000 to check that that is actually related to the problem?

Comment: Error 6 is a launch timeout.  This code will take a while to run the kernel, probably several seconds or more if you are running a debug project.  You are running into a WDDM timeout.

Comment: @RobertCrovella My device is Geforce 840m , the cuda_status returned equals 6 and I am running on windows. What is a WDDM timeout ? and how can I avoid this ?

Comment: @Hurkyl yes It works fine with smaller numbers

Comment: See [this article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/Library/Windows/Hardware/ff570088(v=vs.85).aspx).  There are many questions like this one on the cuda tag as well.

Comment: @RobertCrovella I have the other question. It's the same as mine, Thank you